# how make new rows in a series data frame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a column like this:

```
 col
['A','B','C']
['D','E','F']
['G','K','L']
```

how I can make each of these elements as a row?

```
col
'A'
'B'
'C'
'D'
'E'
'F'
'G'
'K'
'L'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [['A','B','C'], ['D','E','F'], ['G','K','L']]})
>>> df
         col
0  [A, B, C]
1  [D, E, F]
2  [G, K, L]

>>> df.explode('col').reset_index(drop=True)
  col
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   D
4   E
5   F
6   G
7   K
8   L
```

Comment: why it doesn't work for me? it doesn't change anything?

Comment: This answer is correct. Running this will not overwrite your previous dataframe, did you save it to something like "df1 = df.explode('col').reset_index(drop=True)" ?

Comment: `df.explode('col', ignore_index=True)`

Comment: you're right @quang-hoang for `Pandas > 1`. +1